# Laravel data to show with specific value, and specific value have specific date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, controller

I have data in table like this

| id | name | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | ABC | 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 3 | XXD | 3 | 2022-01-01 |
| 5 | ABC | 3 | 2022-01-01 |
| 6 | JON | 5 | 2022-01-01 |
| 7 | WER | 5 | **2022-06-01** |
| 8 | ABC | 5 | **2022-06-01** |

And I want results like this. I want to show data if status >= 2, but if status = 5, I only want to show, data with **created_at >=2022-06-01** AND NAME='ABC'

| id | name | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | ABC | 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 3 | ABC | 3 | 2022-01-01 |
| 7 | ABC | 5 | **2022-06-01** |

I tried in SQL like below

```
WHERE name='ABC' and status BETWEEN 3 AND 4  OR status > 5 OR
      (status = 5 AND created_at >= '2022-01-01');
```

It works in SQL, and show as per expected. But I am confused on how to use it in Laravel controller. It still shows all data.

I tried

```
$query= TABLE::where('status','>=','3')->where('status','<=','4')->orWhere('status','5'5)->where('created_at','>=','2022-01-01)->where('name','ABC')->get();
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE status BETWEEN 2 AND 4 OR status > 5 OR
      (status = 5 AND created_at >= '20220601');
```

This admits records having a status value from 2 to 4, strictly greater than 5, or equal to 5 with a created at date on or after June 1, 2022.

Your Laravel code might look like:

```php
$query = TABLE::whereBetween('status', [2, 4])
    ->orWhere('status', '>', 5)
    ->orWhere(function($q) {
        $q->where('status', 5)
          ->where('created_at', '>=', '20220601');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: thank u tim, it works in sql. can u help me with query in laravel? i try above, but still not show what i expected

Comment: @ezles88 Check the updated answer for some Laravel code.

Comment: @ezles88 this shows why you need to be specific about the answer you require right from the start, else people don't give you the exact info you want.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand that you want all data with status between 2-4 and if status is 5 than check if **created_at >=2022-06-01 AND NAME='ABC'**.

```
    $query = TableName::whereBetween('status', [2, 4])
    ->orWhere('status', '>', 5)
    ->orWhere(function($q) {
        $q->where('status', 5)
          ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', date('2022-06-01'));
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: OP's code shows status greater than 5 also

Comment: just add extra orWhere condition to it as *->orWhere('status', '>', 5)*